# Instafeed.js doesn't show images on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, instagram, instafeedjs

I trying to use instafeed.js for my local site. But I don't understand why images from my account don't show?

My code

Connected instafeed.js and file where I write the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Section for images

```
<section class="instagram-wrap">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="instagram-content">
                <h3>Latest Photos</h3>
                <div class="row photos-wrap">
                    <div id="inst"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and `app.js` with instafeed value

```
$(function() {
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: ID,                
        accessToken: 'Token',
        target: 'inst',
        links: true,
        limit: 8,
        useHttp: true,
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        template: '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="photo-box">
                            <div class="image-wrap">
                                <img src="http:{{image}}"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="description">{{caption}} </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>'

    });
    feed.run();
});
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console on your page?

Comment: Nope. Even Koala dont show any messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works except for this error regarding your template definition:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Put all the template in one line or use `\` at the end of each line to have a [multi-line string literal](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Try write the **template** parameter inline like this:

```
template: '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="photo-box"><div class="image-wrap"><img src="http:{{image}}"/></div><div class="description">{{caption}} </div></div></div>'
```

or on line break insert `\`